# How to get Intel® Centrino® Wireless-n 2230 to work on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, intel-wireless, alienware

I recently got an Alienware M17x with the default wireless card which is an Intel® Centrino® Wireless-n 2230. I have tried the suggested actions by other earlier card versions with no success. I have Internet with Windows if needed.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same problem with my MX14 r2. Can't get any wireless or wired signal on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with same ubuntu version than I wrote below command at terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.3-$(uname -r)
```

and my problem was solved after reboot. if that would not help please check the below links for reference.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2062633

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/Linux-backports-modules

Good luck.